# While implementing mapView i am getting error

Tags: mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKMapView"

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:          "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKMapView"
```

Comment: Have you added The delegate? MKMapViewDelegate ?

Comment: no, hold on i will try.

Comment: Tried but evn then it dint helped :(

Comment: Can you please post the complete error message ?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKMapView"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included the header, so you can compile your code, but you are not linking the binary library, so you can't complete the build process.

```
                           Follow these steps
```

-1.In your target settings, go to Build Phases
 - 2.And in the "Link with binary libraries" section, add MapKit.framework .

Comment: Should i add any delegates ?

Comment: as tamil sail below No need any delegate for this. But you undergoing any operation in UIMapView you need to add "UIMapViewDelegate". Thanks

Comment: ya i need to add mapview .

Comment: Then you can add the <UIMapViewDelegate> . Thanks